# In a Binary Search Tree what is the base of the log for Big O

Tags: performance, binary-search-tree, computer-science

When discussing average time complexity as in this table.

O ( log n )

I'm assuming it is 2 but wanted to verify.  Also is it always 2 for these data structures?

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 2):

In O notation the constants doesn't matter. For example, log2(n) and log10(n) only differ by a constant, so that is why in O notation only log(n) is shown

Comment: I know constants don't matter but I'm not sure that it would be considered a constant.  I get that 5 log(n) and 10log(n).  Are you saying that 2^n and 8^n would both have the same big O as well?

Comment: They didn't leave the 2 out in 2^n on the link I posted.  Do you see the relation?

Comment: Just one example: log2(n) = log10(n) * 3.3219... (long number). Just try with any n and you will see it is true

Comment: This is nothing I'm making up, it is just a property of logarithms

Comment: About if 2^n is the same as 8^n, no, they don't differ by a constant

Answer (score 1):

Roman Cortes got it right in the other answer: it doesn't matter for asymptotic complexity because it's easy to show that `log_a(n) = Theta(log_b(n))` when `a` and `b` are integers greater than one.

However, I think it's still instructive to consider where the `log` comes from in the first place - there certainly is some number associated with its motivation, and understanding that can help you derive these kinds of bounds in the first place.

Binary search trees are constructed to make it fast to search for values. All nodes have at most two subtrees, where all the values in the left subtree are less than the value at the parent and all the values in the right subtree are greater than the value at the parent. When you search a balanced binary search tree (it's important that it be balanced!), you are effectively halving (or close enough to halving) the number of nodes remaining to be searched for the target value. We can express this using the runtime recurrence relation `T(n) = T(n/2) + c`. This says:

> The runtime of the search operation in a balanced binary search tree is given by a constant term from comparing the target to the current node's value (`c`) plus the time to search either the left or the right subtree, but never both (`T(n/2)`).

Assuming reasonably that `T(0) = a` for some constant `a`, we can write out a few values of `T`:

```
n    T(n)
-    ----
0    a
1    T(1/2) + c = a + c
2    T(2/2) + c = a + c + c = a + 2c
4    T(4/2) + c = a + 2c + c = a + 3c
8    T(8/2) + c = a + 3c + c = a + 4c
...
2^k  T(2^k/2) + c = a + kc + c = a + (k+1)c
```

Let `k = log_2(n)`. Then we get `T(n) =T(2^k) = a + (k+1)c = a + (1 + log_2(n))c`. Therefore, `T(n) = O(log_2(n)) = O(log n)`.

Suppose we had a balanced trinary tree where values are ranges and the following rules apply:

1. The target is in the left subtree if the lower limit of the target is less than the current node's lower limit.
2. The target is in the right subtree if the upper limit of the target is greater than the current node's upper limit.
3. The target is in the middle subtree otherwise.

So, this might be a balanced trinary search tree:

```
          (10,20)
             |
  +----------+----------+
  |          |          |
(5,11)    (11,15)    (21,24)
                        |
                     (22,23)
```

Search might work as in binary search, except you check two conditions rather than one and choose one of three possible subtrees rather than one of two possibilities. The recurrence relation becomes `T(n) = T(n/3) + c'` and the solution ends up being `T(n) = a' + (1 + log_3(n))c' = O(log_3(n)) = O(log n)`.